# Пагинация в Codeignither

Tags: codeigniter

Всем привет. Использую, стандартные модуль пагинации в codeignither. Работает все нормально, но когда отправляю Get запрос то он генерирует URL неправильно.

Вот пример.

**URL - https://bigtech.kz/technics/search1**

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'technics/search1';
        $config['total_rows'] = $total_records;
        $config['per_page'] = $limit_per_page;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
```

Работает все нормально.
Но если такой **URL - https://bigtech.kz/technics/search1?id_category=1** при переключении на любую страницу генерируется ссылка типо - **https://bigtech.kz/technics/search1/10** т.е. пропадает get запрос.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение в следующем.
Перед инициализацией библиотеки делаем

```
if (count($_GET) > 0) $config['suffix'] = '?' . http_build_query($_GET, '', "&");
```

И прописываем

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'technics/search1';
$config['first_url'] = $config['base_url'].'?'.http_build_query($_GET);
```